# Apply function with conditions among iterations

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, apply

Imagine I have a data.frame with 5 columns and 3 rows. Within every column, the three data are technical replicates. I would like to do the mean and the SD of each column, so at the end I would have, for each column, a mean and a SD. This is quite easy, I know just with apply function putting 2 as MARGIN. But! What I really need is calculate SD first of all, and IF SD<0.3, then calculate also the mean. IF SD>0.3, then I have to do some combination (see code below; I'm trying this with FOR loop - see below-, but maybe with apply is more efficient and easier but I do not know how to do it).
I have this for loop to do so:

```
MEAN.REF<-numeric()
SD.REF<-numeric()
reference<-data.frame(MEAN.REF=rep(0,length(ref.data)),SD.REF=rep(0,length(ref.data))##ref.data is my data.frame with my data.

for(i in 1:3){
sd.ref<-sd(ref.data[,i])
if(sd.ref<0.3)
{
    mean.ref<-mean(ref.data[,i])
    reference[i,]=c(mean.ref,sd.ref)
}
else 
{
    comb.matrix<-combn(ref.data[,i],2,)#to have the combination matrix as an object
    min.sd<-min(combn(ref.data[,i],2,sd))#select the pair of data which has the minimum sd
    for(j in 1:2)#here R is working upon comb.matrix
    {
        sd.comb.matrix<-sd(comb.matrix[,j])
        if(sd.comb.matrix==min.sd)
        {
            mean.ref<-mean(comb.matrix[,j])
            reference[i,]=c(mean.ref,min.sd)
        }
        else next
    }
}}
```

The problem is that when I work with more than 3 columns, I have problems with the results (there is NA values, 0s...), and I do not know how to solve it.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have you looked at dplyr? You could summarise each column to give you your SD and mean and then use a mutate clause to apply your conditional logic

Comment: there's zero benefit to "declaring" `MEAN.REF` and `SD.REF` btw.